# How can I do intros in a different order without using generalize dependent in Coq?

Tags: coq

Given that I have `forall n m`, is there a way to this:

```
intros n m. generalize dependent n.
```

But in a single step, by only applying `intros` (or an alternative tactic) just to `m`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something along those lines (but with an heterogeneous list in order to be able to apply the tactics to multi-sorted telescopes):

```
Require Import ListTactics.

Ltac introNthAcc n acc := match constr:n with
  | 0    => intro ; list_iter ltac:(fun x => generalize dependent x) acc
  | S ?n =>
     let H := fresh "H" in
     intro H ; introNthAcc n (cons H acc)
end.

Ltac introNth n := introNthAcc n (@nil Prop).

Goal forall a b c, a /\ b /\ c.

 introNth 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the basic Coq tactic language is not very good for this sort of bookkeeping steps. I personally prefer to use the [SSReflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) ones for this, since they are much more economical. Compare

```
intros n m. generalize dependent n.
```

with the SSR equivalent

```
move=> n m; move: n.
```

Notice that if your theorem is a universally quantified fact, you can also put `n` and `m` directly before the colon, thus saving the first `intros` step, e.g.

```
Lemma my_lemma n m : P n m.
Proof.
move: n.
(* Rest of proof *)
Qed.
```

or, even better, if you're doing `induction` right after generalizing,

```
Lemma my_lemma n m : P n m.
Proof.
elim: n.
(* Rest of proof *)
Qed.
```